# How to communicate two plugins of News for Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I have to show in my single page: the single and the list of News with the same categories of single new. I have two plugins in my backend page and have tried to assign the categories of single to the list for typoscript, but i could not do it.

This is the code, i used page.x for debug and catch values:

```
page.100 = TEXT
page.100.data = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news
page.100.wrap = The single tt_news id is: |

page.100.data = GP:tx_ttnews|cat
page.100.wrap = The category of single is: |

page.110 = TEXT
page.110 
{
  value = { register:newsCategoryUid }
  insertData = 1
  wrap = - Categories: |
}

plugin.tt_news 
{
  categorySelection = { register:newsCategoryUid }
  #show only selected categories
  categoryMode = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully visible what you're trying. I think the best way should to put the cat value inside a temp object. Do you have the plugins inserted by TypoScript or as Content Element? You are using tt_news not news by georg ringer right?

```
temp.tx_news_catId = TEXT
temp.tx_news_catId.data = GP:tx_ttnews|cat
temp.tx_news_catId.intval = 1

page.110 < temp.tx_news_catId
page.110.wrap = Category: |

plugin.tt_news 
{
  categorySelection < temp.tx_news_catId
  # you need to use data not categorySelection = {...} <- that should 
  # only work on constants
  # but only works if categorySelection capabilities
  #categorySelection.data = register:newsCategoryUid
  #show only selected categories
  categoryMode = 1
}
```

(Untested TypoScript)

hope this helps you a little bit

PS: Have you checked whether categorySelection has stdWrap capabilities?

Comment: Yes, two plugins are inserted as Content Element and I am using tt_news

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to do, maybe this helps a bit:

If you want to show in the detail action articles with the same category as the current one, you can use a snippet like this one:

Add this to the `Detail.html` which will pass the first category uid to the TypoScript object `lib.tx_news.relatedByFirstCategory`.

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.firstCategory}">
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_news.relatedByFirstCategory">{newsItem.firstCategory.uid}</f:cObject>
</f:if>
```

and the TS:

```
lib.tx_news.relatedByFirstCategory = USER
lib.tx_news.relatedByFirstCategory {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = News
    pluginName = Pi1
    vendorName = GeorgRinger

    switchableControllerActions {
        News {
            1 = list
        }
    }

    settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
    settings {
        relatedView = 1
        detailPid = 31
        useStdWrap := addToList(categories)
        categories.current = 1
        categoryConjunction = or
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
        startingpoint = 78
    }
}
```

I have taken this from the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html).

Comment: Thanks!! This solution help in tx_News but in our current project We are using tx_ttnews. But we will use tx_news in new projects